# template no match call

Tags: c++, oop, templates, casting

i have the following class in .h file:

```
        class T;
    template < class Class, typename ReturnType,typename Parameter1 = int , typename Parameter2 = int, typename Parameter3 = int, typename Parameter4 = int >
    class EventHandlerAbstract
    {
    public:
        // constructors and destructors
        EventHandlerAbstract();
      //  ~EventHandlerAbstract();
        // data types
        typedef ReturnType (Class::*Method)(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3, Parameter4);
      //  test,int Method 

    Method_ ;
        EventHandlerAbstract(Class* _class_instance, Method _method)
        {
            class_instance = _class_instance;
            method        = _method;
        }

ReturnType operator()(Parameter1 parameter1, Parameter2 parameter2=0, Parameter3 parameter3=0, Parameter4 parameter4=0)
{
    return (class_instance->*method)(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4);
}

ReturnType execute(Parameter1 parameter1, Parameter2 parameter2, Parameter3 parameter3, Parameter4 parameter4)
{
    return operator()(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4);
}

static void * makeFunctionPointer(Method _method, Class* _instance_class,Parameter1 parameter1 ,Parameter2 parameter2 , Parameter3 parameter3 , Parameter4 parameter4 );
Class*  class_instance;
Method  method;

static Class callbackType;
static pthread_t threadArray[1];

static std::vector<void *>  callbackList ;
static std::vector<std::string> eventList ;
static std::vector<std::pair <int, int> > eventRelationToCallbackList;
static std::vector<void * > runningCallbackList; // it should to free and thread should free it .
static std::vector<std::string > runningEventList; // it should to free and thread should free it .
}
```

Then, i have the following function in the cpp file:

```
template <class Class,typename ReturnType,typename Parameter1 ,typename Parameter2 ,typename  Parameter3 ,typename Parameter4 >
void * EventHandlerAbstract<Class,ReturnType,Parameter1,Parameter2,Parameter3,Parameter4>::makeFunctionPointer(Method _method, Class* _instance_class,Parameter1 parameter1 = 0,Parameter2 parameter2 = 0, Parameter3 parameter3 = 0, Parameter4 parameter4 = 0)


{
    void * tempCallback;
    ///add_callback
    //
    typedef  typeof(_instance_class) _Class ;
    typedef EventHandlerAbstract<_Class, ReturnType, Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3, Parameter4>  Callback_;
//      _Class _instance = _Class();
    Callback_ classPointer(&_instance_class, &_method);
    EventHandlerAbstract<test,int>::callbackType = classPointer ;
    tempCallback = (static_cast<void*>(&classPointer));
    //(*static_cast< _callback* >(tempCallback))(1,2,3,4); //running a func, a good test
    return tempCallback;
}
```

But When i call in the main function such as the following call, i get error,
my calling:

```
cout << (void *)(EventHandlerAbstract<T,T>::makeFunctionPointer(&test::called,ptr,1, 2, 5, 9)) << endl;
```

or :

```
cout << (void *)(EventHandlerAbstract<test,bool>::makeFunctionPointer(&test::called,ptr,1, 2, 5, 9)) << endl;
```

My error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘EventHandlerAbstract<T, T>::makeFunctionPointer(int (test::*)(int, int, int, int), test&, int, int, int, int)’
```

or

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘EventHandlerAbstract<test, bool>::makeFunctionPointer(int (test::*)(int, int, int, int), test&, int, int, int, int)’
```

i'm confuse, i read FAQ on template on the net, but can't understand my error. 
You will be make me happy if help me...

Comment: I declare test class just for testing this class.not another aspect!

Comment: i changed to &ptr, but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Template function definitions cannot appear in a regular .cpp because they will not be available to the compiler in other .cpps. It's still good to separate the class definition into .h and .cpp, so one solution is to have `#include "myclass.cpp"` at the bottom of your .h file.

Comment: @m_pahlevanzadeh do you mean you included the .cpp in your .h? Maybe your build system si trying to build it anyway due to the extension. You could change it to something like `.icpp`.

Comment: building the templateFunc.cpp file as a regular .cpp is not an issue, it's like building an empty file. The important question is whether it's included in main.cpp